# Where is my internet sharing in Windows Phone Black update?

Tags: 8.0, lumia, lumia-black-update

I have the Nokia Lumia 620 and applied the black update for Windows Phone 8. Now my internet sharing is gone! How do I get it back?

Comment: That depends on your carrier. Who is your cell service provider?

Comment: @interscape so it seems that `Amber` doesn't care about carrier settings?

Comment: @mpapec Maybe his carrier just decided to block this feature witch is strange. User3807 have you tried contact your carrier? Is your phone country variant or it is from a carrier?

Comment: I had this issue too, it disappeared when updating to black. However, when I upgraded to 8.1, I got it back. Nokia black is still there.

Comment: Have you tried SysAppPusher? It can give you most things like that. I'm running Cyan, so I can't check if it gives you Internet Sharing because they replaced it with Access Point. But it does give me Access Point.

Answer (score 2):

By upgrading to **Windows Phone 8.1** should get Internet Sharing back. If not, then it is possible that your carrier has blocked it for your plan and that in order to have Internet Sharing activated again you'll have to switch to a plan with Internet Sharing included.